# Fetch in forEach Javascript to send data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to use Fetch to send data in my mongoDB. 
I would like to read an excel file and then submit each entry in a form.

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="/content" id="importcontent">

     <label for="name" class="col-md-3 label-control">Import XLSX file:</label>         
     <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="file">
     <div style="display: none;">
         <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="titre">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@4.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let importcontent=document.getElementById("importcontent");
    let titre=document.getElementById("titre");
    const input = document.getElementById('file');
    importcontent.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((rows) => {
                input.remove();
                rows.forEach((row)=>{
                    titre.value=row[0]; 
                    fd= new FormData(importcontent);
                    fetch('/content',{
                        method:'POST',
                        body: fd
                    }).then(checkStatus)
                        .catch((error)=>{
                            console.error('request failed', error);
                        })
                });
                }
            });

    });
    function checkStatus(response) {
        if (response.status >=200 && response.status <300){
           console.log("Ok");
        }
    }
```

It isn't working, I have an error 500.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `I have an error 500` - the error is on the server side ... does the content of the response help - if not, does the server side have some sort of error log you can inspect?

Comment: I know the problem is on the server side. What surprises me is that when I send a classic form, it works

Comment: OK, so you know the error is on the server side ... what is the error on the server side that is causing it to respond with a 500 status? some servers send a description of the error as the body of the response when there's a 500 error ... so, check the response body - otherwise you'll need to check any error logs on the server to determine what your code is doing wrong (either the client is sending unexpected data or server is failing for some other reason) - only you can see

Comment: instead of `titre.value=row[0]; fd= new FormData(importcontent);` try `fd= new FormData; fd.append('title', row[0]);`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but isn't work. I have the same error. 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: that wasn't going to fix it, was neater code ... I guess the response in your browser developer tools has no further explanation for the 500 error, and your server has no error logs to show you what you're doing wrong, since you haven't addressed that part of my comments at all

Comment: Sorry. No I don't have any error log in my server. In the console Browser, I just have "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: and every single request gets the same error? there'd be multiple requests. Do any succeed?

Comment: also, what about in the browser developer tools network tab ... is there anything in the `response` for this request that may help?

Comment: so, the server side is node.js express ... how about you do some debugging there

Comment: Hi. I fixed the error. it was in my excel file. I had the bad data. Thanks for you help